# Align button content

Tags: wpf, controls, templates, wpf-controls

I want the content of a wpf button to be left aligned
I tried the following but the text is still centered inside the button.

```
    <Button >
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="Save"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

What do i do?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Found it, it's [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx).

:)

Answer (score 17):

You don't need the StackPanel or the TextBlock. All you need is

```
<Button HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Content="Save" />
```

Comment: my actual implementation had two elements in the content, my example didn't

Answer (score 5):

**You can align in two way, Horizontal and Vertical**

```
<Button Content="Export" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" name="MyBtn1"  />
```

**or**

```
<Button Content="Export" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" name="MyBtn2"  />
```

**See the follow image to view the possibilities settings:**

[image]

[image]